# Can I use accessibility API to fire touch events outside my own app without root?

Tags: java, android, touch-event, accessibilityservice

I was wondering if it's still possible to use the accessibility API to fire touch events outside my own app without having to root my phone. If so, does it work for Android 6.0? Or it requires Android 7.0 and above?

Answer (score 1):

yes or no both;

yes you can press views fill editText but you can't achieve adb shell touch x y this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Yes It is possible to fire touch events outside of your application using GestureDescription. Based on [Android Documents](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/GestureDescription), it requires API level 24(Android 7.0)

you can use other solutions such as rooting device or ADB in lower android versions.

Also, you can use [AccessibilityNodeInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo) to do some actions and it might be useful for your needs. It's also available in Android 6.0

Hope this helps, let us know how it went!